# Set the column width of the Site Contents - Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, sub-site, site-contents

Is there a way to increase the column width of the Site Contents - Subsites list in SharePoint Online (O365)?

The names are getting cut off:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **No**.

Site Contents page in SharePoint online is a one of the application pages. We don't have any SharePoint out of the box way to set the column width from the content on Site Contents page.

Column width drag or narrow/widen options are only available in SharePoint lists and not available for site contents page.

If you want Microsoft to provide such options for site contents page as well, you can add new idea/feedback on SharePoint feedback portal at: [SharePoint Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap.